# PHP to Python port of password encryption

Tags: python, php, openssl, rsa, aes-gcm

I want to convert the following code from PHP to Python.

```
public static function encryptPassword($password, $publicKeyId, $publicKey)
{
    $key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12);
    $time = time();

    openssl_public_encrypt($key ,$encryptedAesKey, base64_decode($publicKey));
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($password, 'aes-256-gcm', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag, strval($time));

    $payload = base64_encode("\x01" | pack('n', intval($publicKeyId)) . $iv . pack('s', strlen($encryptedAesKey)) . $encryptedAesKey . $tag . $encrypted);

    return sprintf('#PWD:1:%s:%s', $time, $payload);
}
```

I have tried the following :

```
import base64
import datetime
import struct
import time

from Cryptodome.Random import get_random_bytes
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_v1_5
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA

def main():
    print(encpass())



def encpass():
    password = ""
    publickeyid = 
    publickey = ""

    session_key = get_random_bytes(32)
    iv = get_random_bytes(12)
    time = str(int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()))
    decoded_publickey = base64.b64decode(publickey.encode())

    recipient_key = RSA.import_key(decoded_publickey)
    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_v1_5.new(recipient_key)
    enc_session_key = cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key)

    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=iv)
    cipher_aes.update(time.encode())
    ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(password.encode("utf8"))

    payload = base64.b64encode((b"\x01\x00"
                                + struct.pack('H', publickeyid))
                               + iv
                               + struct.pack('h', len(enc_session_key))
                               + enc_session_key
                               + tag
                               + ciphertext)    

    return f"#PWD:1:{time}:{payload.decode()}"
```

Would like to know what is wrong in comparison to the PHP code ?

As I am sure it is working but the output is not exactly like the php function..

Thanks

I have updated the code now , i think somewhere in encoding I am wrong , can you detect ?

Comment: The above code is working , thank you to me.